# Помогите с ботом телеграмм на питоне

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot, telegram

```
   import config as cfg

bot = telebot.TeleBot('...')

from subd import Database
db= Database('users.db')

@bot.message_handler(commands=["start"])
async def start(message):
    if message.chat.type == 'private':
        if not db.user_exists(message.from_user.id):
            start_command= message.text  
            referrer_id = str(start_command[7:])
            if str(referrer_id) != "":
                if str(referrer_id) != str(message.from_user.id):
                    db.add_user(message.from_user.id, referrer_id)
                    try:
                        await bot.send_message(referrer_id, "По вашей ссылке присоединился новый пользователь!")
                    except:
                        pass
                else:
                    db.add_user(message.from_user.id)
                    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Нельзя регистрироваться по своей реф.ссылку")
            else:
                db.add_user(message.from_user.id)

        await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Привет! В настоящий момент я нахожусь на стадии <b>-разработка-</b> я не знаю что это,но надеюсь, что то хорошее", parse_mode="html")
    

@bot.message_handler(commands=["profil"])
def profil(message):
    uruurur = f'Имя: <b>{message.from_user.first_name} {message.from_user.last_name} </b>       ID : {message.from_user.id}                  Баланс :' 
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, uruurur, parse_mode="html")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["refkb"])
def refkb(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Ты привел рефералов:  \nТвоя реферальная ссылка: \nhttps://t.me/{cfg.neymb}?start={message.from_user.id}")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["help"])
def help(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Поддержка: ")

@bot.message_handler(commands=["info"])
def info(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f"Мы работаем с {cfg.dts} \nПользователей в боте:   \nАдмин: {cfg.adm} \nКанал Отзывов: {cfg.kanal}  " )
    

bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Код бота

```
import sqlite3

class Database:
    def __init__(self, db_file):
        self.connection = sqlite3.connect(db_file)
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()

    def user_exists(self, user_id):
        with self.connection:
            result = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM 'users' WHERE user_id = ?",(user_id,)).fetchall()
            return bool(len(result))

    def add_user(self, user_id, referrer_id=None):
        with self.connection:
            if referrer_id != None:
                return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id', 'referrer_id') VALUES (?,?)",(user_id, referrer_id,))
            else:   
                return self.cursor.execute("INSERT INTO 'users' ('user_id') VALUES (?)",(user_id,))
```

Код БД

```
RuntimeWarning: coroutine start was never awaited task (*args, **kwargs)
RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemailoc to get the object allocation traceback
```

Ошибка при использовании команды start в боте (а не при его запуске )

Comment: Как вы запускаете бота? Текущий код это не показывает, добавьте [минимальный воспроизводимый пример](/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент по ошибке понятно что не ожидалась асинхронная операция, что приводит к досрочному выходу из функции, посмотрите остальные функции, возможно там нет асинхрона.

А так же в последней строке у вас опечатка, замените message.fro**n**_user.id на message.fro**m**_user.id, скорее всего именно это влияет на работу команды /start

Comment: К сожалению нет, это не помогло, добавил более полный код, заранее благодарю